# All Traffic vs SSH port 22 on AWS security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-groups

I picked "All Traffic" for security groups on AWS but this doesn't seem to permit SSH on port 22? Am I having a nightmare or is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

"All traffic" permits all traffic on all ports using all protocols (TCP / UDP / ICMP). Check your instance firewalls, firewalls at the client side, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[For SSH this is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWoky.png)
But, maybe the issue you are having is somewhere else. Where are you trying to SSH from? Outside AWS or inside? If from outside, make sure you are using the Public DNS Name to SSH.